# Why won't my bash script work?

Tags: mac, bash, unix, terminal, shell-script

I'm getting more comfortable with the terminal in Mac OSX and I thought I'd have a dabble at bash scripting. Not wanting to crawl before I could sit down I wanted to write an incredibly simple "Hello, world!" script so I did this:

```
~/Desktop touch hello.sh
~/Desktop vim hello.sh
```

I then added this to hello.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello, world!"
```

I then did this:

```
~/Desktop chmod -x hello.sh
~/Desktop hello
```

At which point nothing happened.

I had downloaded an equally simple bash script from somewhere that was this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "The current date and time."
date
```

And when I did

```
~/Desktop date
```

it did exactly what it was supposed to.

So then I checked file permissions with ls -l and I got this:

```
-rw-r--r--    1 Mike  staff       33  5 Sep 21:13 hello.sh
-rw-r--r--@   1 Mike  staff       50  5 Sep 21:00 date.sh
```

So clearly the @ is making all the difference, or so I thought. Instead of using vim I created the same file in TextEdit and after going through the same motions as before I ended up with the same situation, ie my script did nothing except now the permissions were showing an @ at the end of them.

So my questions are why is this not working, what am I doing wrong? And what is the @ at the end of the permissions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you must *add* the "execute" permission bit. Using `chmod +x` adds it, `chmod -x` removes it.

Second, in Unix you must use the *exact* file name. If the file is named `hello.sh`, you must run it by **`hello.sh`**, *not* `hello`. (You probably are used to Windows and its %PATHEXT%, which does not exist in Unix. Here, only the execute bit is considered and `.sh` is meaningless to the system – the file *can* be named simply `hello` if you want.)

Third, by default the current directory is *not* searched for commands (for security reasons). Either the script must be located in your $PATH, or you must run it by its full path name. Using `.` (which means "the current directory") will suffice.

```
~/Desktop chmod +x hello.sh
~/Desktop ./hello.sh
Hello, world!
~/Desktop ~/Desktop/hello.sh
Hello, world!
~/Desktop
```

(`./hello.sh` means "`hello.sh` in the current directory".)

When you typed `date`, you did *not* run your own script; you ran the system's `date` command (just like you run the system's `chmod` command when you type `chmod`). The `@` is *not* making a difference here.

The `@` character simply indicates the presence of "extended metadata" associated with that file; most likely something specific to TextEdit. According to the [`ls`(1)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ls.1.html) manual page, you can use `ls -l -@` (`ls -l@`) to see the metadata.

Comment: Thank you very much, a perfect answer. It's working as I expect now.